# How to convert 2d array to 1d array?

Tags: python

I have an array like this.

```
a = ["]['A few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award.', 'Did a few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office annount the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award?'], ['A few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award.', 'When after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award?']"]
```

I want to convert it into 1d list so that i am able to pick random question from that array.

```
after_conversion = [['A few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award.', 'Did a few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office annount the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award?'], ['A few hours after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award.', 'When after the end of his last match in November 2013 the Prime Ministers Office announced the decision to award him the Bharat Ratna Indias highest civilian award?']]
```

when I check the type of the **a** ,it is showing a list.

```
    from itertools import chain
    flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(z))
    flatten_list
    
output
    [']',
     '[',
     "'",
     'A',
     ' ',
     'f',
     'e',
     'w',
     ' ',
     'h',
     'o',
     'u',
     'r',
     's',
     ' ',
```

while using this code, getting an output like this. but i want output as given in **after_conversion.**

Comment: Where does this input come from? Why does it look like that? Consider fixing the code that generates it instead of trying to parse it

Comment: I think something went wrong in copy-and-paste. ```a``` contains a single string that contains Python syntax elements like ``` ], [ ```. It isn't a list of lists

Comment: Your input is invalid Python. Your output is actually a 2D list.

Comment: I agree with @DeepSpace. Otherwise, you are going to have to fix and parse the string yourself. Per StackOverflow's [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should include the code of what you have actually tried.

Comment: first I had an 2d array like **after_conversion**. I wanted to correct a grammar for that i have converted list into string, because without converting into string my for loop was not working.  rrr=str(after_conversion)
`for i in rrr:
  matches = tool.check(i)
  matches = [rule for rule in matches if not is_bad_rule(rule)]
  y=language_tool_python.utils.correct(rrr, matches)
  z=[]
  z.append(y)`
after that i get this array as an output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
 a=a[0].replace(']', '').replace('[', '').replace("'", '')
 l=[]
 l.append([a])
```

or, with a one liner as suggested in the comments:

```
  l = [[a[0].strip("'[]")]]
```

Comment: `append` returns `None`, so `l` is `None` after running this code. Also, it's possible to just use `.strip("'[]")` instead of calling `replace` 3 times (which will provide wrong output if the string happens to have any of these characters in an arbitrary location inside it), and then just create the list directly. In other words, this entire answer can become a single line: `l = [[a[0].strip("'[]")]]`

Comment: Fixed and updated, thanks.
My solution do work for the specific case proposed by the user, so i reject the objection. Cheers and thanks for the downvote eheh

Comment: thank you for your response. now I got the array that I want.  from this new list I want to select random list. for that I am using this code.
 `import random
  random_arr = random.choices(l, k=3)
  print(random_arr)`

but this code will print the same list for **k** times.